# jquery prevent default and browser validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

in my jquery I have this:

```
$(this).click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
... other stuff...
```

I do some extra validation stuff and then I submit a form.
I need this

> e.preventDefault();

to wait with the submit until I did my extra data validation as well as I use bootstrap sweet alerts to do some other checks as well.

But using this, prevents the standard browser validation for fields with required="required" tags. Which is an "visual" pitty.

Is there a way to prevent in jquery the submission and not destroying the browsers validation?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have any default validation. You would need to look at the Bootstrap framework you're using as to how they built in validation first. After e.preventDefault() you would call your own validation code. If you need the default behavior of your framework not to do validation, remove the "required="required"" tags

Comment: @zerohero: The question is about HTML5 validity constraints handled by the browser (not jQuery); see the bit about `required="required"` on an element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm surprised to find that the form's [`checkValidity` method](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-checkvalidity) doesn't do this (it does other things, such as making the browser do its [validity checks](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#statically-validate-the-constraints) and set state accordingly).

Some browsers (including Chrome and Firefox) support `reportValidity`, which does what they do on submit, so you could detect whether that's supported and use it if so:

E.g.:

```
$(this).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.form.reportValidity) {  // <===
        this.form.checkValidity();   // <===
    }                                // <===
    // ...
});
```

...if I assume that what you're clicking is within the form and thus has [the `form` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-fae-form) referring to the form it's in; if not, replace `this.form` with code that finds the form, e.g.:

```
var form = $("selector-for-the-form")[0]; // Note getting the raw element
if (form.reportValidity) {
    form.reportValidity();
}
```

**Example** ([live copy on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qux8quLq/3/)) *(I'm not using Stack Snippets because they don't allow even cancelled form submissions and the code didn't work correctly on Firefox in a Stack Snippet; it **does** work with a cancelled form submission on jsFiddle):*

HTML:

```html
<p>Click the button without filling in the field:</p>
<form>
  <label>
    Required field:
    <input type="text" required>
  </label>
  <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Click to validate">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.form.reportValidity();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! this.form.reportValidity(); solved my issue!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

use the submit event instead of click

```js
$(this).on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
... other stuff...
```

Answer (score -2):

Not very clear what the problem is but as far as I can understand you can:

1. set a flag when you have finished checking your validations
2. instead of preventing the default behaviour check the set flag in
   your `click` function